# An easy way to run tests on a gem?

Tags: ruby, testing, rubygems

Is there a quick and easy way to test a gem which is already installed locally? Like:

```
gem test gem_name_to_test
```

---

[rubygems docs](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11) says one can put `gem: --run-tests` in `~/.gemrc` file to run unit tests when a gem is installed. I could not make it work though and that is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is "gem test" command, which may or may not be what you are looking for. It run tests agains the package and sends them to [test.rubygems.org](http://test.rubygems.org/).

```
gem install rubygems-test
gem test gem_name_to_test
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as of 2012-11-30 on gem -v 1.8.24, and the test.rubygems.org site is reporting "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Answer (score 8):

You can navigate to the place the gem lives and run tests from there, so for example:

```
$ cd ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/awesome_print-0.4.0
$ rake spec
```

Note that additional dependencies may need to be installed via `bundler` or `gem`