# Cannot run rspec (undefined method `belongs_to')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

### UPDATES - 2015-12-09

I'm using Rails 4.2.4 with ruby 2.2.3.

Here is my spec_helper.rb file (generated by generator):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  require 'rails/all'
  require 'json_spec'
  require 'devise'
  require 'rspec/rails'

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include JsonSpec::Helpers
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :request

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Here is my rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production?

# ADDED BY AS #
require 'support/database_cleaner'
require 'yarjuf'
# END OF ADDED BY AS #

require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

# ADDED BY AS #
if ENV['COVERAGE']
  require 'simplecov'
  require 'simplecov-csv'
  SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::CSVFormatter
  SimpleCov.coverage_dir(ENV['COVERAGE_REPORTS'])
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
end
# END OF ADDED BY AS #

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

On `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'
# ruby '2.1.0', :engine => 'rbx', :engine_version => '2.2.6' #rubinius
# ruby '1.9.3', engine: 'jruby', engine_version: '1.7.10'

source 'https://be79af0d:c5a6f6bd@gems.contribsys.com/' do
  gem 'sidekiq-pro', '>= 3'
end

gem 'mime-types',               '>= 2.6', require: 'mime/types/columnar'
gem 'activerecord-import'
gem 'aasm',                     '~> 4.5.0'
gem 'activerecord-colored_log_subscriber'
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'                # Needed by paperclip @ v4.2.1, consider the removal after paperclip gem updates will support awk-sdk v2.
gem 'aws-sdk',                  '~> 2'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'ancestry',                 '~> 2.1.0' # Gestione delle gerarchie ad albero
gem 'auxilium',                 path: 'engines/auxilium'
gem 'barby',                    '~> 0.6.1' # Codice a barre
gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views', '~> 0.0.5'
gem 'cancancan',                '~> 1.13'
gem 'crummy',                   '~> 1.8.0'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'devise',                  '~> 3.5.0'
gem 'devise_security_extension'
gem 'devise-async',            '~> 0.10.1'
gem 'email_validator',          '>= 1.5.0'
gem 'flipclockjs-rails',        '~> 0.7.4', git: 'https://github.com/knightq/flipclockjs-rails.git'
gem 'font_assets'
gem 'google_visualr',           '~> 2.5.1' # Grafici
gem 'hamlit-rails'
gem 'hirefire-resource',        '~> 0.3.8'
gem 'htmlentities',             '~> 4.3.4', require: false
gem 'ice_cube',                 '~> 0.12.1' # Ricorrenze
gem 'jhtmlarea',                '~> 0.1.0' # formattazione testo
gem 'kaminari',                 '~> 0.16.2'
gem 'mailboxer',                '~> 0.13.0' # Messaggistica interna
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'mini_magick',              '~> 4.3.4', require: false
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'paperclip',                '~> 4.3'
gem 'paginate_alphabetically',  '~> 0.3.3', git: 'https://github.com/edendevelopment/paginate_alphabetically.git', branch: 'bundler'
gem 'paper_trail',              '~> 4.0.0' # Record versioning
gem 'pdfkit',                   '~> 0.8.2'
gem 'pg',                       '~> 0.18.4' # PostgreSql
gem 'heroku-api', require: false
gem 'prawn',                    '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'prawn-print'
gem 'prawn-svg',                '~> 0.22'
gem 'prawn-templates',          '~> 0.0.3'
gem 'rack-attack'
gem 'rails',                    '~> 4.2.4'
gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'rainbow',                  '~> 2.0.0', require: false
gem 'ransack',                  '~> 1.7.0' # Ricerche
gem 'render_anywhere',          '~> 0.0.12' # Gemma per il rendering di view in workers
gem 'responders',               '~> 2.0'
gem 'rollbar',                  '~> 2.6'  # Gestione eccezioni
gem 'rqrcode',                  '~> 0.7.0' # Codice QR
gem 'savon',                    '~> 2.0'
gem 'scout_apm'
gem 'sinatra',                  '>= 1.3.0', require: nil
# gem 'sidekiq',                  '>= 3.3.2'
gem 'sidekiq-limit_fetch',      '>= 3.0.1'
gem 'sidekiq-status',           '~> 0.5.1'
gem 'sidekiq-statistic',        '~> 1.2'
gem 'sorted',                   '~> 2.0.3'
gem 'sorted-actionview',        '~> 0.0.1'
gem 'sorted-activerecord',      '~> 0.1.2'
gem 'switch_user',              '~> 1.2.0'
gem 'jc-validates_timeliness',  '~> 3.0'
gem 'when_easter',              '~> 0.3.1' # Calcolo pasqua
gem 'wicked',                   '~> 1.2.1' # Wizards
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary',       '~> 0.9.9.1'
gem 'rubyzip', require: false
gem 'ruby-progressbar', require: false
gem 'templatar'
gem 'tunemygc'
gem 'rqrcode-rails3'
gem 'strip_attributes'
gem 'analytics-ruby', '~> 2.0.0', require: 'segment/analytics'
gem 'activerecord-session_store', '~> 0.1.2'
gem 'jquery-ui-themes',         '~> 1.11.4', git: 'https://github.com/knightq/jquery-ui-themes-rails.git', branch: 'jquery-ui-1.11.x'
# Rubinius-test dependencies
# gem 'racc', platform: :rbx
# gem 'rubysl', platform: :rbx

# jruby-test dependencies
# gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
# gem 'rmagick4j'

# TODO: Test rubinius and jruby with puma

group :production, :staging do
  # gem 'unicorn',                  '~> 4.7.0'
  gem 'kgio'
  gem 'puma',                    '~> 2.15.3'
  gem 'rack-cache'
  gem 'rails_12factor' # see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass',            '~> 2.3.2.2'
gem 'chosen-rails',              '~> 1.4.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',              '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails',        '~> 2.5.0'
gem 'jquery_context_menu-rails', '~> 0.0.4'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails',   '~> 0.4.1'
gem 'jquery-rails',              '~> 4.0.5'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jqgrid-jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails',                '~> 5.0.4'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'select2-rails',             '~> 3.5.9.3'
gem 'uglifier',                  '~> 2.7.2'
gem 'jquery-infinite-pages',     '~> 0.2.0'

group :development   do
  # gem 'better_errors'
  # gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'derailed'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'web-console',               '~> 2.0'
  gem 'hirb',                      '~> 0.7.1'
  gem 'hub', require: false
  gem 'i18n_yaml_sorter'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'peek'
  gem 'peek-rblineprof'
  gem 'peek-git'
  gem 'peek-gc'
  gem 'peek-performance_bar'
  gem 'peek-pg'
  gem 'pygments.rb', require: false
  # gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'stackprof'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'traceroute' # find the dead routes and actions, see: https://github.com/amatsuda/traceroute
end

group :staging do
  gem 'httplog'
end

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.5.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'jasmine-rails'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4.0'
  gem 'seed-fu', '~> 2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'yarjuf'
  gem 'json_spec', require: false
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'simplecov-csv', require: false
end
```

By now, I've only one spec class on `/spec/models/my_model_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe MyModel do

end
```

The server starts and run correctly, but when I try to launch `bundle exec rspec spec` o even simply `rspec spec` I get:

```
/Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:146:in `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:160:in `block in generate_map'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:160:in `each'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:160:in `generate_map'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:145:in `to_app'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/rails.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.4.0/lib/rspec/rails/vendor/capybara.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.4.0/lib/rspec/rails.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/Development/epersonam/spec/spec_helper.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:97:in `configure'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/Development/epersonam/spec/spec_helper.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `require'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `block in requires='
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `each'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `requires='
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `each'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:101:in `setup'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/andreasalicetti/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try adding `require 'rubygems'` to the top of your spec_helper.

Comment: `rspec spec/models/my_model_spec.rb` does not work?

Comment: nope, it does not work. It crashes on boot, exactly on the `require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)`

Comment: Could you try commenting out papertrail gem in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`, then try rspec again.  Just to confirm if your problem is specifically with papertrail gem or with rspec.  If this works then try upgrading papertrail to latest version (3.0.2)

Comment: Already done: it is not something related to that gem.

Comment: The error clearly _is_ related to the gem. So how does the error change if you exclude the gem?

Comment: I've updated the description with console output post `paper_trail` gem remotion and even after further removal of `ransack` gem.

It does not solve: shall I go on removing gems?

Comment: It looks like when the external libraries are loaded, rails has not yet been loaded...

Comment: I think the problem is in one of the models.

Comment: Is ARel in your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Also, maybe try adding this to the spec_helper file: 

   require 'paper_trail/frameworks/rspec'

Comment: can you specify the following version and try updating your gems with bundle update rspec-rails and see if the problem still exists?
 gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'

Comment: The first file contents in your question might need to be stored in `spec\rails_helper.rb`, but you said `spec\spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: what do you get when you try and run `bundle exec rspec .` ?

Comment: @Isotope I've added the output you asked at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti, I see in your Gemfile, that you have fixed most gems to a version, however the rspec gem (and some others) is not. Could it be that you have updated this in the past, now leading to all these errors? Maybe looking the version up per "gem list" and trying to revert to an older version could help.

Comment: I've updated my question, that was quite obsolete due to later changes

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti, as it seems rspec related you could try running tests against the rspec gem itself and see if we obtain a more verbose error message; possibly this could serve as a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586591/an-easy-way-to-run-tests-on-a-gem

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing one or both of these lines:

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/autorun'
```

My RSpec runs well without them.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't the gems themselves, it's the order things are loaded. Please change the top lines of the spec helper to this:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

Basically, I think you're trying to load the application before rubygems and other dependencies which may be why @dankohn 's answer failed.

Comment: nope, I've tried also in this way, but it raise an error on line 4 (`require 'rspec/rails'`) saying:

    /.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/action_view/template.rb:8:in `<class:Template>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Autoload (NameError)

Comment: "actionpack-4.0.12" but you say you're using rails 3.2? There's a problem there, it should be 3.x. You've run `bundle` right? I'm thinking there might be an issue with your rbenv / bundler config

Answer (score 1):

Use this gem [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)

It is one of the best gem to write rspec for associations

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile, most gems are fixed to a version, as is the rails gem. However rspec and pry are not fixed, hence get updated. Probably finding out what the initial version of your rspec was, fixing it in the gemfile and running a *bundle install* helps.

In case you have not explicitly uninstalled gems, *gem list* shows you earlier versions.

Comment: No, we are use to check each single gem when update (and we never run a direct `bundle update`). It is not a problem with rspec.

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti, what is the version of your railties gem (_gem list_ )? It should be ~> 3.0

Comment: 4.2.4, I'm on Rails 4.2.4

Comment: Have you tried to create scoped binstubs?  $ bundle install --binstubs
$ bin/rspec spec/models

Comment: Yes, even if the `bundle exec rspec` should do the same. However, unfortunately, it does not work... :-(

Comment: Could you please post the output of $ gem list?

Answer (score 0):

In your code replace `Version` with `PaperTrail::Version` wherever you are using `Version`.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not an error about class name: it's about class loading...